# Remove margin around pantheon windows in i3?

Tags: elementaryos, i3-window-manager

It seems that Pantheon applications mess with i3 by adding a huge gap between windows/frames like in the screenshot below.

[image]

Is there a way to use Pantheon applications in i3 without that border/margin? I guess it's the shadows of Pantheon applications that cause this, so is there a way to disable them?

(I'm running Elementary OS 0.4 x86_64 with i3 v4.11. My previous desktop manager was lightdm v1.18.3, which is still installed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what did it for me:

- `cd` into `~/.config/gtk-3.0` (create it if it isn't there)
- `touch gtk.css` or append to `gtk.css` if it already exists
- In your favorite text editor add the following:

  ```
  .window-frame {box-shadow: none; margin: 0;}
  ```

Save it, logout, log into i3wm and you should be good to go.

Comment: YAY!  You are welcome.  I was really happy to discover this.  And although I don't always use the i3 session, when I go to school for coding this is going to be extra handy.

Comment: So, I am currently having a problem with this.  I will keep you updated on any new progress.

Comment: After getting back to eOS' default DM, I noticed that handles for resizing windows were missing. But to get them back without the ugly black margin in i3, just use `.window-frame {box-shadow: none; margin: 2px;}`.

Comment: Does the original solution still work for you though?

Comment: Yes, it does. Neither Pantheon nor i3 are broken in any way, when using this CSS hack, and there's no black margin around my windows in i3. (You need to fix the colon between `none` and `margin` though)

Comment: I will try again.  It seems as though I cannot make this work anymore, and I assume that there wouldn't be any significant changes to gtk or gala to make it not work anymore.

Comment: Well, no dice for me.   I am having numerous problems with this, from the gtk hack not working, to my touchpad tap to click not working, to chrome getting confused on the login credentials.  

I might have to put this on the back burner for now.

I really would prefer to stay on elementary, but I simply have got to have this working.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your gtk.css with me?  I cannot understand why mine doesn't work, but it just refuses to work for me.  

And aside from a total wipe and reinstall, I do not know what to do.

Comment: My `gtk.css` file in `~/.config/gtk-3.0` contains just `.window-frame {box-shadow: none; margin: 2px; }`. In the same directory there is a `settings.ini` file as well, but it just darkens my theme with `[Settings]\ngtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1` where `\n` is a new-line. I don't of any other modifications DM-related modifications to my system besides the i3-installation. Although I'm not experienced with Pantheon/i3-configuration, if you have any error messages or clues, I might be able to help.

Comment: So, I fail.  I misunderstood what you said earlier about the colon.

It's all working now.

At least that much is.

Comment: This works for main windows, but doesn't appear to work for "pop-ups". Specifically, when I go to create a new email in pantheon mail.